# Roboelectric error when extending AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, robolectric

I am using roboelectric 3.0 and when i run a simple Acitivity tests I get the following error

```
  You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:113)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
    at com.paveynganpi.ballonor.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
    at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethod(ReflectionHelpers.java:195)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:122)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:305)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter$2.runPaused(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:45)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:118)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:129)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.setup(ActivityController.java:210)
    at org.robolectric.Robolectric.setupActivity(Robolectric.java:46)
    at com.paveynganpi.ballonor.LoginActivityTest.validateLoginButtonText(LoginActivityTest.java:34)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:245)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:185)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:149)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:48)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:105)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

com.paveynganpi.ballonor.LoginActivityTest > validateLoginButtonText FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at LoginActivityTest.java:34
1 test completed, 1 failed
```

My Main activity extends AppCompatActivity. I am actually using Theme.Appcompat as you can see in my styles.xml file below

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

My test is as below

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class LoginActivityTest {


//    @Before
//    public void setup() throws Exception {
//        mLoginActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(LoginActivity.class);
//        assertNotNull("MainActivity is not instantiated", mLoginActivity);
//    }

   @Test
    public void validateLoginButtonText(){
        MainActivity mainActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
        mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.action_notification).performClick();

        Intent expectedIntent = new Intent(mainActivity, NotificationsActivity.class);
        assertThat(shadowOf(mainActivity).getNextStartedActivity()).isEqualTo(expectedIntent);

    }
```

Comment: What version of robolectric are you using? See https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/840

Comment: am using version 3.0

Comment: i saw that post. It didnt help

Comment: If you're using Gradle, try using RobolectricGradleTestRunner instead. If you still have problems, please also show your build.gradle file.

Comment: Just want to say the solution provided by Alex works !! ++